# Reading CPU registers on STM32

Tags: cpu-registers, stm32

On STM32F4, how can I read a CPU register?

Are these registers mapped anywhere in memory?

If not, can you please provide a simple assembly code for reading a register (LR for example) into a local variable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Keil toolchain I used this approach:

```
register int R0 __asm("r0");
```

where 'R0' is now recognized by compiler as variable.

Search for 'Named register variables' e.g. :

http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359125006491.htm

Answer (score 2):

First off, if you're simply trying to peek into program execution, you should just download the IAR Embedded Workbench for ARM (**IAR EWARM**) size-limited version (no trial-end date).

- You can create a new project, drag-and-drop your code to it, and even run it in the simulator (e.g. choose "Simulator" in Project->Options->Debugger). Then you can ***profile all the registers you want***.

But if you really want to do it in code...well it depends on which registers you want to read, what *you* want to do with them, and what the compiler decides to use them for.

**General-purpose registers** are going to be used however the *compiler* decides it wants to use them, so you need to understand the underlying assembly to understanding what they represent.

Your local variables are usually stored in GPR's, so reading the value of a local variable (in c code) ***is*** essentially performing a register-read in this case.

Reading **Special-purpose registers**, such as the LR, is probably going to require assembly. For example, you could write a pure-assembly function that returns the LR of the calling function, and then call that function from c-code.

For example, from `main`, one might execute `x = lr_return_func();`, where `lr_return_func()` is a pure-assembly function that copies the LR used in `main` (stored on the stack above function parameters) to register R0 (used for return values). When `lr_return_func` returns, this LR would then get stored in `x` (e.g. some register back in main).

You *could* do it with in-line, but you need to determine which register your local variable is using first. So if you determine that `x` is being stored in R4 for example, then your inline assembly would want to copy the LR to R4, and be done...essentially storing your LR in `x`.

Comment: Hello? Is there anybody out there? Just nod if you can hear me

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the delayed response. The effort is very much appreciated. A coding example would be great. BTW, it's "Is there anybody **in** there" (not "**out** there").

Answer (score 1):

There is a good tool available for Eclipse, called EmbSys Registers.
It's really handy even though sometimes it lags

Comment: I think this should be a comment rather than answer, but considering you currently don't have enough reputation to comment I think it is OK.